# Need Highlighted row as per the if/else conditions in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing script to monitor servers and get the result in html when threshold is crossed for memory,cpu and cdrive. My script is running but I am not getting accurate highlighted rows when condition is met in if/else statement.

```
# Path for the CSV file that contains all the Print Server information.
        $ServerDetails=import-csv "C:\cn.csv"
        $result=@()

         foreach($server in $ServerDetails){

         try{    

             #sysinfo variable contains complete systeminfo like manufacturer name, physical memory,servername 

             $cpu=Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName $server.servers win32_processor| select __Server, @{name="CPUUtilization" ;expression ={“{0:N2}” -f (get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 |
                select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).average}}

             $disks =Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Volume -ComputerName $server.servers -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'" |
                Select-object @{Name = "PercentFree"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f  (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity)*100) } }


             $os=gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $server.servers |
                Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }}

        $result += [PSCustomObject] @{  
            ServerName ="$($server.servers)" 
            CPULoad = $cpu.CPUUtilization
            CDrive = $disks.PercentFree
            MemLoad = $OS.MemoryUsage

            }
            }
            catch{
         "error communicating with $($server.servers), skipping to next"
         }


    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> Server Health Report </TITLE>
                     <BODY background-color:peachpuff>
                     <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le"">
                     <H2> Server Health Report </H2></font>
                     <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                     <TR bgcolor=gray align=center>
                       <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD>
                       <TD><B>CPULoad</B></TD>
                       <TD><B>Memory Utilization</B></TD>
                       <TD><B>CDrive</B></TD></TR>"


    Foreach($Entry in $Result) 

        { 

          if(($Entry.CDrive) -le "65") 
          { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
          }
          else
           {
            $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
          }
          if(($Entry.MemLoad) -ge "70") 
          { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
          }
          else
           {
            $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
          }
          if(($Entry.CPULoad) -ge "15") 
          { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
          }
          else
           {
            $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
          } 

            $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CPULoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.MemLoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.Cdrive)</TD></TR>" 
    }
      $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
      $out=$Outputreport | out-file C:\Test.htm 


 }

    }
```

for ex:-my cpu threshold is set for greater than equal to 15, but I am getting rows in red where none of the threshold condition is met or only one of them either of memory or Cdrive is met. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the foreach loop with this.

```
Foreach($Entry in $Result) 
{ 
    if([decimal]$Entry.CDrive -le 65 -or [decimal]$Entry.MemLoad -ge 70 -or [decimal]$Entry.CPULoad -ge 15) 
    { 
        $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
    }
    else
    {
        $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
    }

    $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CPULoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.MemLoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.Cdrive)</TD></TR>" 
}
```

**Issue and Fix**

You are comparing string with strings when comparing the Entry field with certain threshold.  You need to compare the numbers with numbers, decimal in this case. If you dont use [decimal] before the Entry's field, then it compares it with its default type of String, which doesnt work.

Following is the test I performed,

```
$result.CPULoad                   # output: 9.74

$result.CPULoad -gt "10"          # output True
[decimal]$result.CPULoad -gt 10   # output False
[decimal]$result.CPULoad -gt 9.74 # False
[decimal]$result.CPULoad -gt 9.73 # True
```

**UPDATE**

If you are looking to get % Bytes In Use (Memory Utilization) as well, you can run the following command

```
$mem = Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName server.servers win32_processor| select __Server, @{name="MemUtilization" ;expression ={“{0:N2}” -f (get-counter -Counter "\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 |
                select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).average}}
```

Comment: Great! The script is working fineone more point I want to clarify is in the script I am getting average CPU for a period of time by specifying sampleinterval in the command. I also want to add same timing to get average memory usage for a period of time in $os variable. I have tried the same get-counter command but not getting proper result.

Comment: @RujhaanBhatia see my update ... how you can get the memory utilization

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, my script is working fine now. One more thing I want to add on is that I am getting mails when it is crossing the threshold, but is there any way that script monitors the server for sometime atleast 30 minutes and then it send the mail. I have increased the sample interval time in $cpu command but it takes too much time to give the result. I have scheduled my script on one server, if I schedule it on all the servers will that be more convenient or not.

Comment: @RujhaanBhatia please do mark the post as answer if it answered your original post. Regarding timing, you have to remember each monitor will take their own time to get the results... 30 mins for CPU plus 30 mins for memory and additional time for other monitors. What I can suggest is taking numbers for each in 1 or 5 min interval and save them in a list separately. Then average the numbers when emailing. You can also run jobs so they all run in parallel to give you true monitoring

Comment: I just encountered one error while script execution that when I run script using PowerShell ISE it works fine but same script when scheduled to run from task scheduler gives me incorrect result. Is there any alternate to schedule script instead of task scheduler?